# Help the dealer rebuild the deck

Tags: code-golf

The dealer has been sloppy and lost track of what cards his/her deck contains and what cards are missing, can you help him/her?

---

A complete deck consists of 52 playing cards, namely:

Each color in the deck (hearts, diamonds, spades, clubs) contains:

- The numbers [2 - 10]
- A Jack
- A Queen
- A King
- An Ace

---

**Task**

Your program will read the contents of the deck from STDIN until a newline is read.
You can assume that the input will be in the form of "nX nX nX nX" etc. where:

- n - any number between [2 - 10] **or** either 'J', 'Q', 'K' or 'A'.
  (You can assume upper case only for non-numeric characters)
- X - any of the following : 'H', 'D', 'S', 'C' (You can assume upper
  case only)

Where:

- 'J' = Jacks
- 'Q' = Queen
- 'K' = King
- 'A' = Ace

And

- 'H' = Hearts
- 'D' = Diamonds
- 'S' = Spades
- 'C' = Clubs

You can assume that there will be no duplicates in the input.

Your program must then print the missing cards in the deck to STDOUT in the same fashion as the input ("nX nX nX") or print 'No missing cards' if all 52 cards are supplied. 
There is no constraint on the order of the output of the cards.

Example input:

```
9H AH 7C 3S 10S KD JS 9C 2H 8H 8C AC AS AD 7D 4D 2C JD 6S
```

Output:

```
3H 4H 5H 6H 7H 10H JH QH KH 2D 3D 5D 6D 8D 9D 10D QD 2S 4S 5S 7S 8S 9S QS KS 3C 4C 5C 6C 10C JC QC HC
```

Happy golfing!

Comment: Could we use `T` instead of `10`?

Comment: @Arnauld I'm afraid this is all the information the dealer gave me so you'll have to stick with '10' or he'll get moody.

Comment: @GillBates Doesn't `J` represent `10`, though?

Comment: @Okx `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A`. `J` represents `11`.

Comment: @Okx `J` is the 10th letter of the alphabet, but that's not what this is about. :)

Comment: Can input be `['nX', 'nX', 'nX', …]`?

Comment: Are leading/trailing spaces allowed? Is it okay if the cards are separated by arbitrary amounts of spaces?

Comment: Can we use some other separator other than the space?

Comment: @kritixilithos Yes, yes.

Comment: @kritixiLithos No

Answer (score 8):

### Windows Batch (CMD), <s>205</s> 204 bytes

```
@set/pc=
@set d=
@for %%s in (H D S C)do @for %%r in (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A)do @call set d=%%d%% %%r%%s
@for %%c in (%c%)do @call set d=%%d: %%c=%%
@if "%d%"=="" set d= No missing cards
@echo%d%
```

Loops over the suits and ranks building a complete deck, then deletes the input cards. Save 1 byte if `T` is allowed instead of `10`. Save 11 bytes if command-line arguments are acceptable input. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @user202729.

Comment: I count 200 bytes.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino As I'm on Windows, I use Notepad to save the file, which means that newlines cost me 2 bytes instead of one. I'm too lazy to use a different editor to save bytes.

Comment: Oh lol okay. I get 200 bytes using Sublime Text.

Comment: @Neil On Windows you can use LF instead of CR LF, saves 5 bytes (HyperNeutrino comment above) and it still work.

Comment: Also, you can pass `/v` to CMD (+3 byte?) to `EnableDelayedExpansion`, eliminate `call` in the for loop. / Seems that you have an extra space between `(%c%)` and `do`?

Answer (score 8):

## Python, <s>147</s> <s>146</s> <s>145</s> <s>138</s> <s>131</s> <s>129</s> <s>127</s> <s>125</s> 120 bytes

```python
print(' '.join(set(`x`+y for x in range(2,11)+list('JQKA')for y in'HDSC')-set(raw_input().split()))or'No missing cards')
```

Gets all possible cards as a set and subtracts the input cards.

-1 byte thanks to mbomb007 pointing out an extra space in my code.
-1 byte thanks to mbomb007 for pointing out some golfing that can be done with Python 2 (-5 bytes and +4 bytes for `raw_` in `raw_input`)
-7 bytes by switching to using sets and set subtraction instead of list comprehensions
-7 bytes thanks to ValueInk for pointing out that I don't need to `list` the suites
-2 bytes thanks to Datastream for pointing out that just writing out all of the values is more byte-effective than the weird thing I had earlier
-2 bytes thanks to ValueInk for pointing out that sets can take generators so I don't need to put it in a list comprehension
-2 bytes thanks to Datastream for pointing out that I can golf it down even more if I switch to Python 3 again... (+2 for parens after for print, -4 for `raw_`)
-5 bytes thanks to Lulhum and myself for pointing out that by switching back to Python 2 (!!!) can help me save bytes (using range again, using backticks instead of `str(`, and +4 due to `raw_`)

Comment: You have an extra space you can remove, and you can use `\`d\`` instead of `str(d)` if you use Python 2, in addition to removing the parens for `print`.

Comment: `for y in 'HDSC'` also works for getting all the characters in there. (You still need `list('JQKA')` for the other part, though.)

Comment: `'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A'.split()` Might save a few bytes instead of the `[`d`for d in range(2,11)]+list('JQKA')` manipulation you have going on.

Comment: Agreed, it seems like it will save 2 bytes on account of the fact that `1` doesn't need to be added. Also, you can remove the outer brackets for your first list comprehension because the `set` constructor takes in generator objects just fine.

Comment: @ValueInk Yep, used both suggestions and it saved 9 bytes overall. Thanks!

Comment: So has it come full circle that swapping to python 3 saves 2 more bytes? +2 for adding the `()` for print. -4 for removing `raw_`

Comment: @Datastream Oh wow, that's funny. Thanks!

Comment: @Datastream converting the list items to string is shorter. `set(str(x)+y for x in range(2,11)+list('JQKA')for y in'HDSC')` save 6 bytes over `set(x+y for x in'2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A'.split()for y in'HDSC')`

Comment: Absolutely. Unfortunately, @Keerthana Prabhakaran beat us all with his implementation below(specifically setting up the deck). :P I wonder how close we are to the record of most rewrites for one golf?

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 39 bytes

```
ðIð¡YTŸ"JQKA"S«"CDHS"SâJsKðýDg>i“Noœ¶‡¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#DY49asNQEISv8qETJPqxpCYgdovNexB4bJqcIKRKkQv4DmnTOG0aVcaNGz18EV9EWfhmi2WYmb2uz3XdTm@vt0uTSl4a3/4aUfPG62/6ynWtV31/@rgff14@b9/b@X48bed9n43FGIXOORiPD05WkjMLrTEFwhI4izIqvdIKSTl4uCWkIaONv9NFkNIZvdDHdQZhUAYjBUJRilGcImQjR10YojsChTGmOJMyxQBl9n8)

**Explanation**

```
ðI                                       # push space and input
  ð¡                                     # split on spaces
    YTŸ                                  # push the range [2 ... 10]
       "JQKA"S«                          # append ['J','Q','K','A']
               "CDHS"Sâ                  # cartesian product with suits
                       J                 # join each card with its suit
                        sK               # remove any cards in input from the list of all cards
                          ðýDg>i         # if the length of the resulting list is 0
                                “Noœ¶‡¶  # push the string "No missing cards"
                                         # output top of stack
```

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```
B,2>"JQKA"+"HDSC"m*:slS/-S*"No missing cards"e|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#DcJBCsIwEEDRq3xmWRU1irUuhDizCCkIMicQFSlYBbP17rGPV0/zcJR86aPMJJmrjM2hvHy58EbOH8ahlOH95Hb93os8frV2iZholY2zXjm9kZ1OCYn9VIlTJxqtsTWCko2d/wE)

**Explanation**

```
B,                    e# The range from 0 to 10
2>                    e# Slice after the first two elements, giving the range from 2 to 10
"JQKA"+               e# Concatenate with "JQKA", giving the array containing all ranks
"HDSC"                e# The string containing all suits
m*                    e# Take the Cartesian product
:s                    e# And cast each pair to a string. Now a full deck has been constructed
l                     e# Read a line of input
S/                    e# Split it on spaces
-                     e# Remove all cards from the deck that were in the input
S*                    e# Join the result with spaces
"No missing cards"    e# Push the string "No missing cards"
e|                    e# Take the logical OR of the result and the string, returning the
                      e#   first truthy value between the two. (empty arrays are falsy)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 39 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
9R‘Ṿ€;“JQKA”p“CDHS”F€œ-ɠḲ¤Kȯ“¡¢ıḍĖ9ṭƥw»
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#FY29agJxEMR7n2JeQFDvm1THLrLcvzr3RdKlPdKnCoQUEVS0U0KsFMHi0JA8xt2LXCbN7uwMv9mhWPTNe3e@9s/7h775qOpQ9s3ykVLUnHLO5P46/l11p2O7DT@fjNp1u7l9daeX21vRnQ/fu6f2MgyJYiYoBLkhp@BpqBWRYjpxZILYEAQRM0cqSAwzR23IDKUgdQRHRUxR0xdUhsgICzICioSWI1bETpdLEAwVUUNC@v8RfzsKdipKR87JEkepoz8)**

#### How?

```
9R‘Ṿ€;“JQKA”p“CDHS”F€œ-ɠḲ¤Kȯ“¡¢ıḍĖ9ṭƥw» - Main link: no arguments
9R                                      - range(1,9)    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  ‘                                     - increment     [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   Ṿ€                                   - uneval each  [['2'],['3'],['4'],['5'],['6'],['7'],['8'],['9'],['10']]
     ;“JQKA”                            - concatenate with char-list "JQKA" [['2'],['3'],['4'],['5'],['6'],['7'],['8'],['9'],['10'],['J'],['Q'],['K'],['A']]
            p“CDHS”                     - Cartesian product with char-list "CDHS" [[['2'],['C']],[['2'],['D']],...]
                   F€                   - flatten each [['2','C'],['2','S'],...]
                         ¤              - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad
                       ɠ                -     read a line from STDIN
                        Ḳ               -     split on spaces
                     œ-                 - multi-set difference
                          K             - join with spaces
                            “¡¢ıḍĖ9ṭƥw» - compressed string "No missing cards"
                           ȯ            - logical or
                                        - implicit print
```

Answer (score 5):

## C#, 343 bytes

First time posting one of my golfs, not a very good contender though. I'm sure I can reduce this more.

The idea behind it is a sparse array storing occurrences of cards, with indexes calculated by the ASCII values of the different values and suits multiplied against each other (e.g. an ace of spades (AS) would be stored in the area at index (65 * 83 = 5395)). This way, each type of card gets a unique index that can be checked later for existance in the "map" array.

```cs
void M(string[]a){var c=new int[]
{50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,49,74,81,75,65,72,68,83,67};var e=new 
int[9999];int i=0;int j=0;foreach(var s in a) e[s[0]*s[s.Length-
1]]++;int f=0;for(i=0;i<13;i++)for(j=13;j<17;j++)if(e[c[i]*c[j]]==0)
{f=1;Console.Write(((i<9)?(i+2)+"":(char)c[i]+"")+(char)c[j]+" 
");}if(f==0) Console.WriteLine("No missing cards");}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>114</s> <s>111</s> 110 bytes

```powershell
param($n)('No missing cards',($a=(2..10+'JQKA'[0..3]|%{$i=$_;"CSHD"[0..3]|%{"$i$_"}}|?{$n-notmatch$_})))[!!$a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#PcjNaoNQEAbQ/fcUidxylbaSXv8pocjMYlAoyCxDkEsKiQtNidklPrvd9SzP@utvfgzNFIX2@7oZh3kepvPm5G8/s30Ljd@HLo4/dq@26draHnZxnByfLw8z7E3/GZAKB/8ZmMH0wbI8vx5mep@u99HfTxfTL1EUHbZb44/rulpHcAoncIyEkCgSQcJICakiFaSMjJApMkHGyAm5IhfkjIJQKApBwSgJpaIUlIyKUCkqQcVoCI2iETSMjtApOkHHaAmtohW0jJpQK2pBzfYP)

Takes input `$n` as either a space-delimited or newline-delimited string. Constructs an array from the range `2..10` concatenated with `JQKA` (indexed with `[0..3]` to make it a `char` array). That array is fed into a loop `|%{}` that sets helper `$i` then loops over the suits to concatenate the results together with `$i$_`. At the end of this loop, we have an array of strings like `("2C", "2S", "2H", ... "AH", "AD")`. That array is fed into a `Where-Object` (`|?{}`) with the filter as those elements `$_` that regex `-notmatch` the input `$n`. The result of that filtering is stored into `$a`.

Then, we use a pseudo-ternary `( , )[]` to select whether we output `'No missing cards'` or `$a`, based on whether `!!$a` turns to a Boolean `$false` or `$true`. If `$a` is empty (meaning every card in the deck is in the input), then `!!$a` is `0`, so the `"No missing cards"` is selected. Vice versa for `$a` being selected. In either case, that's left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + coreutils, 89

```bash
sort|comm -3 <(printf %s\\n {10,{2..9},A,J,K,Q}{C,D,H,S}) -|grep .||echo No missing cards
```

I/O as a newline-delimited list.

#### Explanation

- `sort` reads newline-delimited input from STDIN and sorts it
- This is piped to `comm`
- `printf %s\\n {10,{2..9},A,J,K,Q}{C,D,H,S}` is a brace-expansion to generate the full deck of cards.  The `printf` prints each card on its own line.  The order is given such that the output is the same as if it had been piped to `sort`
- `comm` compares the full deck against the sorted input and outputs the difference.  `-3` suppresses output of column 3 (the common ones)
- The whole output from `comm` is piped to `grep .`.  If there was no output from `comm` (i.e. all cards were in the input), then the `||` "or" clause outputs the required message.  Otherwise the `grep .` matches all lines output from `comm`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#DcK9CoMwFAbQ/XuKuxRauIo/pVboEpIhKBRKVpdirXXQSOJmfHbr4ezeuiW0dhwpyulxnt0wLV86@aaZaE0TXrM4LjcWXHHNr22VrFiz2S4Uhd51M8UhdO3P0tPSOHg/TD21b/fx@15qCI1CIjdIE4NaoTIoJTKN@1FCHA2EQqFwVcgkKoWb@QM).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),<s>104,93,130</s>,114 bytes

```python
r=input()
print' '.join(n+x for n in list('23456789JQKA')+['10']for x in'HDSC'if n+x not in r)or'No missing cards'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FY67asQwFET7fMXpZLMk7PrtIoWRiosNAaMypFi82UQhkRbbgf3x1I4Mc2GKM3dmm5@dv/2uSfpwm51fFerpKzif@MOda5jxOM@3W9ZEZXlRVnXT9uPQqfTwqk5H9bYz98goMVYrd2UP@rDusTkNs3oJ/Lhlcf6D6TxfFrVtqhU6odbkltPRMhh6S6vJhCZK00VZOkNtKAyZpjdUlix6Sy7khlxTCIWl0JRCaSgtpaYSqghr6thhaQxNfG5oLb3Qa0ZhNIyWUTMIQxyg4w6JZ9SfD4/Tefp8/wc)

- -10 bytes with hardcoding the list instead of using range!
- +37 bytes - missed printing 'No missing cards' if all cards are present in input!
- -16 bytes by modifying the code into a list comprehension!

Comment: Doesn't print "No missing cards"

Comment: @L3viathan thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my answer!

Comment: The `list('23456789JQKA')+['10']` is clever. I was wracking my brain for a better way to split the `10` out of the list of single chars in the other python answer, but that works beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 108 + 1 = 109 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag.

```
a=[*?2..'10',?J,?Q,?K,?A].map{|i|%w"H D S C".map{|c|i+c}}.flatten-$_.split;$_=a==[]?"No missing cards":a*' '
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 143 Bytes

```
foreach([H,D,S,C]as$c)foreach([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A]as$v)$r[]=$v.$c;echo join(" ",array_diff($r,explode(" ",$argn)))?:"No missing cards";
```

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 157 + 1 (`-r` flag) = <s>170</s> 158 bytes

```sed
x
s/$/;A2345678910JQK/
s/.+/&H&D&S&C;No missing cards/
:
s/(10|\w)(\w+)(.);/\1\3 \2\3;/
t
G
:s
s/(10.|[^ ;1]{2})(.*\n.*)\1/\2/
ts
s/[ ;]+/ /g
s/^ //
s/ N.+//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#Jc1Bi8IwFATge37FHJbSWuxrUrXWnEoCWyoIkqNPQRSkh20XI7iw@tftRhbmMAwfzPgjPH2QrlUxmy/KZSXzdrumMGYpRU1kIxcZvRnw1Xnf9RecjtezJ7EKIpb5g@9JzPc0ibNEE0suwIoLTeImPsXK/6vssTtAy/2vegY44T6bJCyJVWBvsoPepwS6hH4Avd@xCf80jlWDukFpUDjI3GFt0TpUBqrBMsSgDnGoLUqLmYUyaC0W7jV837qh9@P0@gc)

This generates all possible cards and then remove each card in the input from the generated cards.

Comment: Doesn't print "No missing cards"

Comment: @L3viathan Fixed

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>117</s> <s>114</s> 111 bytes

```js
s=>[...Array(52)].map((_,i)=>~s.search(c=('JQKA'[v=i>>2]||v-2)+'CDHS'[i&3])?_:c+' ').join``||'No missing cards'
```

This takes advantage of the fact that *undefined* entries in the array generated by `map()` are coerced to empty strings when `join()`'d.

#### Demo

```js
let f =

s=>[...Array(52)].map((_,i)=>~s.search(c=('JQKA'[v=i>>2]||v-2)+'CDHS'[i&3])?_:c+' ').join``||'No missing cards'

console.log(f('9H AH 7C 3S 10S KD JS 9C 2H 8H 8C AC AS AD 7D 4D 2C JD 6S'))
```

Answer (score 2):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/0018fae00fc41bff1ac6681e4e5b2412), 282 bytes

---

**Golfed**

```cs
i=>{var o=new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();string[] S={"H","D","S","C"},N="A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K".Split(' ');foreach(var s in S){foreach(var n in N){if(!System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(i,n+s)){o.Add(n+s);}}}return o.Count>0?string.Join(" ",o):"No missing cards";};
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
i => {
    var o = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    string[] S = { "H", "D", "S", "C" }, N = "A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K".Split(' ');

    foreach( var s in S ) {
        foreach( var n in N ) {
            if( !System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains( i, n + s ) ) {
                o.Add( n + s );
            }
        }
    }

    return o.Count > 0
        ? string.Join( " ", o )
        : "No missing cards";
};
```

---

**Ungolfed readable**

```cs
i => {
    // Initialize a list to contain the list of cards missing
    var o = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    
    // Initialize the list of suits and numbers of cards
    string[] S = { "H", "D", "S", "C" }, N = "A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K".Split(' ');

    // Cycle through the suits...
    foreach( var s in S ) {
        // ... and the numbers ...
        foreach( var n in N ) {
            // ... and check it the combo number + suite is missing
            if( !System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains( i, n + s ) ) {
                // If it's missing, add it to the list of missing cards
                o.Add( n + s );
            }
        }
    }

    // If the count of missing cards is greater than 0...
    return o.Count > 0
        // Build a 'space' separated string with the missing cards
        ? string.Join( " ", o )
        // Or output the missing cards string
        : "No missing cards";
};
```

---

**Full code**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Namespace {
   class Program {
      static void Main( String[] args ) {
         Func<String, Int32> f = i => {
            var o = new List<string>();
            string[] S = { "H", "D", "S", "C" }, N = "A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K".Split(' ');
            
            foreach( var s in S ) {
               foreach( var n in N ) {
                  if( !i.Contains( n + s ) ) {
                     o.Add( n + s );
                  }
               }
            }
            
            return o.Count > 0
               ? string.Join( " ", o )
               : "No missing cards";
         };

         List<String>
            testCases = new List<String>() {
                "9H AH 7C 3S 10S KD JS 9C 2H 8H 8C AC AS AD 7D 4D 2C JD 6S"
            };

         foreach( String testCase in testCases ) {
            Console.WriteLine( $"{test}\n{f( test.Split( ' ' ) )}" );
         }

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.0** - `282 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

**Notes**

Nothing to add

Comment: This is a very nice format for your answer, +1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 76 bytes

```
^
A2345678910JQK¶ 
\G(10|.)
 $&H $&D $&S $&C
Dr` \S+
G1`
^$
No missing cards
```

Input/output is a list of space-separated cards. Output has a leading space.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#DcNBCsIwEAXQ/ZziL4oogiRpbZplyEBDCoLMtpQWBelChXbruTyAF6uB97aBvCmrc20bp1W6dr8vqG/3Wn1OB0KxiznnkgfiZUQvR2r1SENBlzee87rOrwdu03Jft81F@AgbUAq0EnSMJHABJqLJAnwm8AzLqBgmIDFq@QM)

#### Explanation

Most of the code deals with building the full list of cards that should be in the deck:

```
^
A2345678910JQK¶ 
\G(10|.)
 $&H $&D $&S $&C
```

First, we prepend a newline to the input, with all possible values of cards, then for each character of this line (or the couple of characters `10`) we build the list of all possible suits of that card.

```
Dr` \S+
```

This is a deduplication stage, it splits the string into chunks consisting of a space plus some non-spaces and keeps only one occurrence of each chunk. The modifier `r` makes this operate from right to left, keeping then the *last* occurrence of each chunk.

```
G1`
```

We keep only the first line, which now contains the missing cards.

```
^$
No missing cards
```

If the result is empty we replace it with "No missing cards"

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 106 bytes

Combination of the two previous python answers mixed with some string unpacking shenanigans.

```
print(' '.join({x+y for x in[*'23456789JQKA','10']for y in'HDSC'}-{*input().split()})or'No missing cards')
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 116 bytes

```julia
print(join(setdiff(["$x$y"for x=∪(2:10,"JQKA")for y="HDSC"],readline()|>split),' ')|>s->s>""?s:"No missing cards")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5daoNQEIW3crgEomAh8S8aiEVmHi4KBZnH0odQtdxgNXgtJNAFdC1dVjdib@AbmDMc5pzL12DO6bpeZzMu3mUyo2e7pTV9772qzW1zV/0043b6@/n1wuN@F6iqqUvlP673k9IspN6CuTu3gxk7z/8u7HUwix9ssX2Ip8IWSj3bo3qZ8GmsNeMH3s9za5W/rrlGqXEgRIL9TlAzKkFOCDUyB6F0CErGgREzQkLFSAWh2wWRRsSICLFGLIgJiUbCSAQJIdVInZlwcBmCjJG554xcUGlUhEajYTSChlBr1K4AuR7aDf8D)

Very similar to Kyle Gullions python solution. Setdiff instead of - and the lambda to test for the empty string make it worse though.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 39 bytes

```
"JQKA"¬c9õÄ)ï+"CHSD"q)kU ¸ª`No ÚÍg Ößs
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=IkpRS0EirGM59cQp7ysiQ0hTRCJxKWtVILiqYE5vINrNiGcg1t9z&input=WyI5SCIsIkFIIiwiN0MiLCIzUyIsIjEwUyIsIktEIiwiSlMiLCI5QyIsIjJIIiwiOEgiLCI4QyIsIkFDIiwiQVMiLCJBRCIsIjdEIiwiNEQiLCIyQyIsIkpEIiwiNlMiXQo=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), <strike>270</strike> 228 chars

(Shortened with some help from Wît Wisarhd)

```
foreach s {H D S C} {foreach c {2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 J Q K A} {dict set d $c$s 0}}
gets stdin l
foreach c $l {dict set d $c 1}
set m {}
dict for {c h} $d {if {!$h} {lappend m $c}}
if {![llength $m]} {set m "No missing cards"}
puts $m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BasMwEETv/orXoA9InDSOj8Y6GAcKRcfSQ5Ac2yA7JlJOQt/uqimlUJjD7s5jZr2263q93buLHnCEBomijoTfoybk7DnwypGCEyUt75ypEmRG7XGdxyC0cGxjzPrOO5w344zN/lKE/Yezi9n3PBFi9nQSTNAMEWEI45XwItIS7GVZutkkUuhU8DQ@rO3m3g@I6TMhP0GbtxvT6Nw49@jL3bhNzJZHekdM61o2VA1FzV6x2yrOklZR1uQNp6SaKklRSQrJQZLXtJKj@gI)

Explanation:

This implementation builds a dictionary consisting of a boolean flag for
each of the cards represented by the cartesian product of H D S C and 
2-through-A. It reads the line from stdin, which if given as the spec 
as called for, is actually a well formed Tcl list. As each card is read,
a boolean true is input in the dictionary for that card.

At the end a parser loops through the dictionary, and adds any card that
did not have a true in the dictionary to a list of missing cards. If the
missing cards list length is zero, output "No missing cards", otherwise
output the list of missing cards.

Comment: [There is a whole lot of extra whitespace in your answer.](https://tio.run/##XY3LisIwGIX3fYpPyQOo43UpzmIYQRCX4qIksQ2ktfjHVciz16iI4O5cPs4J2vf9@XK1pa4R4h@/HNgk4jvUxAk/TJkxZ8GSFf/s2bLOkHE6IDZgUFoJo5SKygZBgnEtvvisKP@FM07FQzfEVDybDBM1dUIZojsTByqb6Muus63JpNL54FEcvbdtFWpUc8pEd8ufqklYL/Zlh7sLjRNxbYUur0aGqe/v "Tcl – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 138 bytes

Ran with `-n` and `-d error_reporting=0`

I reuse some code from an [old submition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166666/77963) i made that asked for create a deck of cards

**Code**

```php
<?$r=[];foreach([A,J,Q,K,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]as$t)array_push($r,$t.H,$t.S,$t.D,$t.C);
echo join(" ", array_diff($r,explode(" ",$argv[1])));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBa4NAFAbv/RUfYQ8KL0VNGiM2FNk9iDmVPYoEiWu0FHd52tL@@W5jC8NchnGD8/75RfCpbvLesmmvQ1AXVNErnSmhHe3piQ6U0pEyiqOmncUStszt98V9zEMgmMTyWK7Sq9QqGeYP5jpYvNlxCjbYEP6Xbuz7dTFf7t125i@Jlm@fddyEYZh777MSRYlUYqcRRxpnhUojk0hKHO9IFHc0CoVUYa@QSFQKB/1j3TLaafbbyW87GGbLFzbO8jJOt1P0Cw)

**Explanation**

```php
<?$r=[];   # Declare the array that will contain the full deck
# the next line will generate the arry with the full deck  
foreach([A,J,Q,K,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]as$t)array_push($r,$t.H,$t.S,$t.D,$t.C);
# explode the input string on each blank space and using array_diff to get the
# different elements withing both arrays. (and "echo" of course) 
echo join(" ", array_diff($r,explode(" ",$argv[1])));
```

Comment: You can get it down to 120 with a few tweaks. 1) end the first line with a ?> replace the 'echo ' with <?= 2) entering the cards on regular command line with spaces will populate $argv as an array with each as an element, so you can remove the explode() entirely. [Try it](https://tio.run/##JcvNCoJAFIbhfVcR4ULhFGY/JmUiMwuxVcxSIobStIUzHC3o5vvKgpdn99raArvE4bg4bSvDpb7UbpFSTkc6UEALWtKK1hTShiKa@yfdOb2nmfXrbB9d7TpMTj/LBtSAHBBesh/tkvhumtadjCf0H65NVf0Gzben520BRBnSDKHAQmHuKxwkcoVIIMiw@SaQflNIJUKJpUQgkEus1dvYvjFth2mL6XVcMhs@c2kN9017i/0P)

Comment: i had no clue that `$argv` can work like that, thanks @gwaugh

Comment: Oh btw @gwaugh the question sayd that the argument is a string separated by spaces, can set the arguments one by one.

Comment: If you run it on the command line like:  'php deck.php 2S 5H JC' it's the same use as if you were to think of it as a space delimited string. You're just letting PHP parse it out for you. It's only the UI of TIO that makes you put them in separate.

Comment: Oh, i see. Will edit, thanks for the -bytes :D

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 197 bytes

Without LINQ.

```cs
s=>{var w="";for(var j=0;j<52;){var u="";int t=j%13;u=t<1?"K":t<2?"A":t<11?t+"":t<12?"J":"Q";t=j++/13;u+=t<1?"H":t<2?"D":t<3?"S":"C";w+=s.IndexOf(u)<0?u+" ":"";}return w==""?"No missing cards":w;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBfb4IwFMXf@RQnTZZA2JzgNqcFCYEsTPefhz0jVFOjZWmLbjF@dlZwT0tvcm77O6e5uaW6KmvJ2kZxsUb@ozTbUavcFkrhTdZrWeyOFvDVLLe8hNKFNrKveYXnggvb6SDw0IgyUFqaPy5x1hmWCFsVzo77QuIQEkJXtbS7yyYc0k1w61OnZ03HuNDQ4ebCG9Em1IEXkQWZ6sCPSNyp50XaJX1nnuZkSt4JNX7Xve4S7jmS/UXSTkcRyY0vIfTghmrwKCr2/bqyGycYRo1LYBihJ8l0I4WZzwwRkZcaO676VZSFrBSZHuiJttQ6L2aQ1ELVWzb4lFyzJy6YvbT/oQ9WVD1xHIda1smcdpIhzjBOMMrhDXMsUsxzTBL4Ge5NJYhN5YhTjFPcpPATzFPcGWeGXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 73 bytes

```perl6
put keys((<<{^9+2}J Q K A>>X~ <C S D H>)∖get.words)||"No missing cards"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchNCoJAAIDRq3y4UoIoC00QYZhZDApBzKZVECUi/SiOEZG17gQdsItMwlu9tuzOkXPtredUPqzvp@lzl0zCV86GApFl2zepxKDQWfD7fKuyn96b7miDYfDWDZfa2vpacdiP5zmXaIQmliwM85mhUOSGRBJqViOJGBmEIlYsFaEkV0TmDw)

Some pretty simple set subtraction between the deck of cards and the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 102 bytes

```python
lambda s:' '.join(i+j for i in[*'A23456789JQK','10']for j in'HDSC'if(i+j)not in s)or'No missing cards'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYs7D4IwGEX/yt0@qsbwkoeJA2kHAomJ6agOKEFLpCUUB389luRM95w7/ua30dHSnW7LpxkebQN7JNC@N0p7atujMxMUlL5uqAij@JCkWV5datpR4NN9tb2zVArJSXXrhWkzuwmWmYnOBoOyVukXns3UWlrGSenZc6Uev7PHGFvyEkWJlCOSCHyJWqCSyDnCEpmDo3BIFAKpQCwQclQCifwD)